# How to detect &ensp; in string

Tags: java, html, character

I have the next string

```
String s = "Stack Overflow § 15-45";
```

Please, notice that whitespace after section sign is `0x2002 or EN SPACE or &ensp; or &#8194;`

I want to detect this character in string and replace it with ordinary whitespace. Here is my example

```
String s = "Stack Overflow § 15-45";
        char[] input = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            char c = input[i];
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c)){
                input[i]=" ";
            }
        }
```

Could you please help and answer is this a good solution or there is a better one?

Comment: You could use `Regex.Replace(s, @"\s", " ");`. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own solution is fine. If you prefer, you may do

```
    if (c == '\u2002') {
```

The number 2002 after the u is interpreted as a hex value giving the unicode character you want.